# ui5 issue table binding working randomly under 1.71

Tags: binding, sapui5

Under v1.71, my code is working randomly (litteraly, sometimes the table displays the items correctly sometimes it doesn't) although it is perfectly working under v1.6+.

I'm working under 1.17.21

My default model is two-way binded.

The table is created in the xml view :

```
<Table id="tableId" items="{Items}" delete=".onDeleteRow" mode="Delete" noDataText="{i18n>noItems}">
                        <headerToolbar>
                            <OverflowToolbar>
                                <Title text="{i18n>addedItems}" level="H3"/>
                                <ToolbarSpacer></ToolbarSpacer>
                                <Button icon="sap-icon://add" press=".onAddItemPress" tooltip="{i18n>addButtonTooltip}"/>
                            </OverflowToolbar>
                        </headerToolbar>
                        <columns>
                            <Column hAlign="Center" minScreenWidth="Small" demandPopin="true" popinDisplay="Inline">
                                <header>
                                    <Label text="{/#PRItem/ShortText/@sap:label}"/>
                                </header>
                            </Column>
                            <Column hAlign="Center" minScreenWidth="Small" demandPopin="true" popinDisplay="Inline">
                                <header>
                                    <Label text="{/#PRItem/Quantity/@sap:label}"/>
                                </header>
                            </Column>
                            <Column hAlign="Center" minScreenWidth="Small" demandPopin="true" popinDisplay="Inline">
                                <header>
                                    <Label text="{/#PRItem/PriceUnit/@sap:label}"/>
                                </header>
                            </Column>
                            <Column hAlign="Center" minScreenWidth="Small" demandPopin="true" popinDisplay="Inline">
                                <header>
                                    <Label text="{/#PRItem/Price/@sap:label}"/>
                                </header>
                            </Column>
                            <Column id="editIconColumn" hAlign="End" width="50px"/>
                        </columns>
                        <items>
                            <ColumnListItem>
                                <cells>
                                    <Text text="{ShortText}"/>
                                    <Text text="{Quantity}"/>
                                    <Text text="{Quantity}"/>
                                    <Text text="{parts [path:'Price', path:'Quantity', path:'PriceUnit'], formatter: this.formatter.setSousTotal}"/>
                                    <core:Icon src="sap-icon://edit-outside" press=".onEditIconPress" tooltip="{i18n>editIconTooltip}"/>
                                </cells>
                            </ColumnListItem>
                        </items>
                    </Table>
```

And I bind the view context and items as follows:

```
_createPurchaseRequest: function () {
        var oContext = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel().createEntry("/PRHeaderSet");

        this.getView().setBindingContext(oContext);
        this._getDefaultValues();
},

onAddItemPress: function (oEvent) {
        var oView = this.getView(),
            // oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel(),
            oModel = this.getModel(),
            oHdrCtx = oView.getElementBinding() ? oView.getElementBinding().getBoundContext() : oView.getBindingContext(),
            oItemContext = oModel.createEntry("/PRItemSet"),
            aAllItems = this._getArrayOrDefault(oModel.getProperty(oHdrCtx.getPath() + "/Items"));

        aAllItems.push(oItemContext.getPath().substring(1));
        oModel.setProperty("Items", aAllItems, oHdrCtx);
        this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("createViewModel").setProperty("/mode", "creationMode");
        oModel.setProperty("Quantity", "7", oItemContext);
     },

    _getArrayOrDefault: function (e) {
        return e ? Array.from(e) : [];
    },
```

The aggregation("items") is correctly binded but sometimes its properties aKeys and aAllKeys are empty so the table doesn't display anything.

When working:
[image]

Not working (after trying to add an item or more)
[image]

A comparison between a working case (left) and a non working one (right) :
[image]

Can anyone see the isse?

Comment: I had slightly similar problems, it turned out that I had duplicate (not unique) keys in my backend

Comment: Well I've checked and it's purely an issue from frontend, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't really understand but I managed to resolve my problem by giving more time to the framework to make two independents operations which are setting the context to the view and get the defaults values. I mean independents here because I don't need those default values to set the context et I could get those values without setting the former.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you code right, as [documented](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2#loioadd47c3966dd40489e952bb4f5f74a7c)

> Do not modify objects or values inside the model manually; always use
> the provided API to change data in the model, or use two-way binding
> (see Two-way Binding section below).

What you are doing is not officially supported. Use only API methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I understand what you're saying and I checked the docs especially the deep create part which is done differently from my app, unfortunately I can't do the same here because I can't create the parent without the child...

Comment: Creating local a few Lineitems and ten pressing save() can't be done with public APIs. Use eather a json model and move all on save with one batch request. Or send it directly to the backend and refresh the list. Deep create is a leftover from prior batch times. Not sure if I would ever use it nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

In your onAddItemPress function, don't add the item to the table like that because UI5 will not like it. Instead you must use an OData Create (see docs) to create the entry in the back end, which will then automatically trigger an update to the binding of the entity set on the table and make it appear.

There are a couple of different ways to do this depending on how you want it. In summary the two different ways you could do it are an OData Create to create the entry in the back end immediately. Alternatively, you could use createEntry to create a local entity in your OData Model which you can then populate the data for either through binding to a popup form, or in code or whatever, and then use the submitChanges function to send that to your OData provider and create the entry. The advantage of the second way is that you can also have a "reset" button in your app where the user can discard the changes before they are ever sent to the server. Of course that is also possible with the first option, but it would involve sending a delete request for the object you created.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already use the createEntry API to create my entries but still had this issue.
I considered your idea of creating the entry directly to the backend but I want to make very few requests so I didn't opt for this.